# node.js read images from PDF

Tags: node.js, pdf

I need to use `PDF` in a way similar to `ZIP`/`RAR`. To hold many images (ancient tibetan buddist literature), ideally 60000. But splitting in 10-100 volumes is OK.

Anything can be used for packing, but for unpacking we need `Node.js`. Because same `PDF` file must be served on web. But some users will need to use whole `PDF`.

So the question is, what `node` module I can use to read any single arbitrary image from huge `PDF`? Example would ***really*** help.

Every image is a single page. (Or in otherwords every page is single image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have been using https://github.com/mirkokiefer/Node-Magick for this....

But the pngs we get out sometimes are fairly low quality..